# How to Identify which user is sending request to submit_sm function in SMPP using node.js

Tags: node.js, session, smpp

I am new to node js. I am using this smpp package.

**https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp**

When user connects to the smpp server with System ID & Password, I authenticate the user the return the response.
Now, When user submits the request to send SMS to submit_sm, I want to know which user is sending the request.

Please help me!

I was thinking to add an object with unique identifier in session when there is bind_transceiver request, So when user hits submit_sm, At that time I can extract the object from session to identify the user. But not sure If it is the right way.

Comment: No one answered! I guess no one knows about it. 
I found it. 
session._id can be used to determine which user is connected to the server.